# When is norm surjective mod an ideal for global fields?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Given $K/k$ Abelian, for which ideals of $\frak p\unlhd\cal O_k$ will we have $N^K_k:\cal O_K\rightarrow\cal O_k/\frak p$ surjective?  $k$ is an algebraic number field.

In his article "On the norm groups of global fields", Stern wrote that the norm function is never surjective for Abelian local extensions of global fields.  Can surjectivity still be salvaged if we are looking mod an ideal?  In particular, if the ideal is either small enough, or has certain properties (like not being ramified), then this should be possible: especially since the latter group is finite.

I am getting a feeling this is either completely obvious, or else there is some higher-level terminology in which my question should be rephrased to get an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathcal O_{\mathcal K}^x$?  The fractional ideals of $K$?  Or the units of the ring of integers of $K$?

Comment: Thank you, the x was a typo.  Just $\cal O_K$.

Comment: I'm gonna try it, give me like 20 minutes.  Just checking: do you mean $\mathfrak p$ to be a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_k$, or any old ideal?

Comment: Ideally, we want to find all ideals which have this surjectivity: not just the prime ones.  But if primes are all we can show, that will work too.

Comment: In fact, if one of the primes dividing p is ramified, then surjectivity cannot be shown...

Comment: Ohh, but why not?

Comment: Sorry, this comment was hidden behind the "Show 1 more comment" button.  But I think I figured it out: please look over my answer to make sure I am not missing something fundamental.  If there's any way I can award you points for trying, let me know.

Comment: [deleted comment]

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $N$ the norm in the finite extension of number fields $K/k$. Because the norm of an integral element is an integral element, $N$ restricts to a map  $O_K$ -->$O_k$, still denoted by $N$. If $Q$ is a prime ideal of $O_K$ lying above a prime ideal of $ P$ of $O_k$, $N ( Q) = P^f$ (where $f$ is the inertia degree) is contained in $ P$, hence induces a map $O_K / Q $--> $O_k /  P $. But these residue fields are finite , hence the norm is surjective. Finally, your original map $O_K$-->$O_k / P $ is surjective because it factors through $O_K / Q $-->$O_k / P $. Note that we don’t need $K/k$ to be abelian, not even Galois.

If $K / k$ is an abelian extension of local fields, then local CFT says that the norm index $(k^* :N(K^*))$ equals the degree $[K : k]$. For an abelian extension of global fields, see e.g. the question « Index of norm group of a global field », posted by Jack Yoon, May 9'16.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly partial answer; at least someone please look over and see if I am missing something:

If $\frak p = \frak p_1^{e_1}\cdots\frak p_r^{e_r}$, then by CRT, surjectivity of $\cal O_K\rightarrow\cal O_k/\frak p$ is equivalent to surjectivity of each of the $\cal O_K\rightarrow\cal O_k/\frak p_i^{e_i}$.  So it suffices to show this for $\frak p$ prime power.

Now if $\frak p$ lifts to $\frak (P_1\cdots\frak P_r)^e$ (ramification degree is the same because the extension is Galois), then $N(\frak P_i) = \frak p$ is in the kernel of the above map; so it suffices to assume that $N:\cal O_K/\frak P_1\cdots\frak P_r\rightarrow\cal O_k/\frak p$, and both groups are finite.
In such a case, it is a standard argument that the induced norm map ($\frak P_i\mapsto\frak P_1\cdots\frak P_r$) will be surjective.  However, if $\frak p$ is ramified, then the $N$ map sends $\frak P_i$ to $(\frak P_1\cdots\frak P_r)^e$, and so it equals the induced norm map ^e.  In this case, if ($e, |\cal O_k/\frak p|$) $\neq$ 1 [which I believe happens every time the extension is ramified?], then we only get the set of $e$-th powers in $\cal O_k/\frak p$, and so the map is not surjective.

Tracing backwards, given an ideal $\frak p$ we can figure out whether or not the norm map mod that ideal is surjective.

Comment: The norm is a multiplicative map, right?  If you're taking the norm from $\mathcal O_K$ to $\mathcal O_k$, and then reducing modulo $\mathfrak p$, then you're just looking at a function, not a homomorphism.

Comment: I assume you're trying to show that for any coset $a + \mathfrak p$, for $a \in \mathcal O_k$, that there exists a $b \in \mathcal O_K$ with $N_{K/k}(b) - a \in \mathfrak p$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to show.  I will think about the "function" vs. "homomorphism" tomorrow: perhaps it affects applicability of the CRT?

Comment: I think it affects implications of words like "kernel."  Also, are you perhaps confusing the ideal/global norm with the finite field norm?  Those are different things.